# Change the language in my Libreoffice

Tags: 13.10, libreoffice, language-support

I use Ubuntu 13.10 and I have installed Libreoffice by ppa.

But it is in english.

I want to change for portuguese.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Choose Tools - Options - Language Settings - Languages"

"Escolha Ferramentas - Opções - Definições de idioma - Idiomas"

- https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Selecting_the_Document_Language